# MySQL Server 5.7.34 installation failed

Tags: mysql, sql, installation, configuration

While installing the MySQL Server, I got this error. Please help me with installation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHKuD.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking a question. Do NOT post pictures of text (code, errors, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

it may arise if you have installed 64 bit Visual Studio but the installer is 32 bit so maybe installer is not  recognizing Visual Studio. Try installing 32 bit version.